# workbox webpack 4 plugin unable to precache non-webpack assets

Tags: reactjs, webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox-webpack-plugin

I am looking to precache images for a PWA, using [this documentation.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin)

I have tried several iterations, but I am struggling with the globs.

Here's one instance of the plugin code on my `webpack.config.js`:

```
     new InjectManifest({
        swSrc: './client/sw-src.js',
        swDest: '../sw.js',
        exclude: [/\.twig$/],
        globPatterns: ['/img/*.{svg,jpg,webp}']
    }),
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
/public
    /dist => there's where the 'regular' webpack assets are
    /img => directory I want to add to precache on top of /dist
    ...
```

I have also tried to use `globDirectory`, with no luck.

It works if I manually add the code below to my `sw-src.js` file, but that is not ideal and prone to errors.

```
 workbox.precaching.precache([
'/img/circles.svg',
'/img/concept-1.jpg',
......
]);

workbox.precaching.addRoute();
```

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing worth mentioning is that Workbox works with webpack assets that have been added to the compilation output. It's possible that you have files in the build context, like images in your repository, but they need to actually be required or otherwise added to the output.

One easy way to achieve this is to use [`copy-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin). This is really useful when migrating to webpack from other build tools or when your dynamically constructing asset URLs and aren't using webpack loaders.

EDIT: Adding setup with actual solution:

This is the new directory setup:

```
 /assets/img/  => origin directory for copy-webpack-plugin
 /public
   /dist => there's where the 'regular' webpack assets are
   /img => destination directory for copy-webpack-plugin
```

And the actual code for copy-webpack-plugin and also adjusting the clean-webpack-plugin

```
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public/dist/*.*', 'public/img/*.*']),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './assets/img/', to: '../img' },
      ]),
```

Comment: Your solution worked. I took the liberty of editing your answer to add actual code, pending approval. Thanks very much.

Comment: Note that the `globPatterns: ['/img/*.{svg,jpg,webp}']` code on the `InjectManifest` plugin is no longer needed.